# What problem is it when I want to map these documents to these 3 different labels?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I am completely new to machine learning, and that means I am new to the ML-related jargon too.

I have a problem at hand where there about a 1000 documents (on an average 500 words each) which need to be mapped to 3 different classes.

Each class is defined based on some real-life concept like Cancer, Drug, children. These concepts are backed by certain taxonomy/controlled vocabulary. For example, MeSH terms for Cancer/Neoplasm.

What problem is it when I want to map these documents to these 3 different labels? Only when a document is mapped to all the labels, then a document is considered a positive match. Should I use pattern matching for it or Machine learning?

Comment: what you mean by "Only when a document is mapped to all the labels, then a document is considered a positive match"?

Comment: It is to filter a document (as positive instance) only if it belongs to all the predefined 3 categories simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me your problems fits just fine as a [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification).

I am not sure there exists an approach that would seek whether a text belongs to more than one category simultaneously. Nonetheless, I also see no problem for you to take a more heuristic method involving consolidated text classification algorithms.

For example, imagine you train a model to classify documents into three labels $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Now, you input a new, unseen document to to this model. Any of the [mainstream libraries](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-model-comparison-and-selection-5eb066197568) will output the likelihood of this document belonging to each of the labels (individually, of course). For example:

```
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+
|     DOC      |  A  |  B  |  C  |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+
| new_document | 80% | 69% | 51% |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

All you have to do now is establish a threshold for which you'll consider that the document belongs to all three labels simultaneously. In the example above, if the threshold is 50%, then you consider it a match.

Comment: Thank you for point me to the problem class. I looked more into it. do you think it is a multi-label problem instead of a multi-class problem?

Comment: @ftTomAndJerry indeed, you are right. Classes are mutually exclusive. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Exactly, the challenge then will be deciding a sensible threshold for the individual labels.